# Variable not being inserted into another variable for some unknown reason: Converting text to binary

Tags: batch-file, cmd

From what I can see, the variable '!text%%b!' is not being set into the variable 'number' for some unknown reason. This weird error prevents me from continuing the code and I see no reason for it not working.

```
@echo on
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%1"=="/?" (
    call :help
    exit /b
)
if "%1"=="/b" (
    set text=%2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
    call :convBinary
    exit /b
)
if "%1"=="/t" (
    set text=%2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
    call :convText
    exit /b
)
echo [CONV] That command is not recognized.
exit /b

:help
echo Converts any text or binary to either text or binary.
echo.
echo    Stynax: CONV [conversion] {options} [text]
echo.
echo    /b     Converts given text to binary.
echo    /t     Converts given binary to text.
echo.
exit /b

:convBinary
for /L %%a in (0, 1, 100) do (
    set text%%a=!text:~%%a,1!
)
for /L %%b in (0, 1, 100) do (
    if "!text%%b!"=="A" (
        set text%%b=65
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="B" (
        set text%%b=66
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="C" (
        set text%%b=67
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="D" (
        set text%%b=68
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="E" (
        set text%%b=69
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="F" (
        set text%%b=70
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="G" (
        set text%%b=71
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="H" (
        set text%%b=72
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="I" (
        set text%%b=73
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="J" (
        set text%%b=74
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="K" (
        set text%%b=75
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="L" (
        set text%%b=76
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="M" (
        set text%%b=77
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="N" (
        set text%%b=78
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="O" (
        set text%%b=79
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="P" (
        set text%%b=80
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="Q" (
        set text%%b=81
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="R" (
        set text%%b=82
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="S" (
        set text%%b=83
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="T" (
        set text%%b=84
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="U" (
        set text%%b=85
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="V" (
        set text%%b=86
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="W" (
        set text%%b=87
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="X" (
        set text%%b=88
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="Y" (
        set text%%b=89
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="Z" (
        set text%%b=90
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="a" (
        set text%%b=97
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="b" (
        set text%%b=98
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="c" (
        set text%%b=99
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="d" (
        set text%%b=100
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="e" (
        set text%%b=101
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="f" (
        set text%%b=102
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="g" (
        set text%%b=103
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="h" (
        set text%%b=104
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="i" (
        set text%%b=105
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="j" (
        set text%%b=106
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="k" (
        set text%%b=107
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="l" (
        set text%%b=108
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="m" (
        set text%%b=109
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="n" (
        set text%%b=110
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="o" (
        set text%%b=111
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="p" (
        set text%%b=112
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="q" (
        set text%%b=113
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="r" (
        set text%%b=114
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="s" (
        set text%%b=115
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="t" (
        set text%%b=116
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="u" (
        set text%%b=117
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="v" (
        set text%%b=118
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="w" (
        set text%%b=119
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="x" (
        set text%%b=120
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="y" (
        set text%%b=121
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="z" (
        set text%%b=122
    )
    if "!text%%b!"=="" (
        set text%%b=
    )
    set ascii=!ascii! !text%%b!
    set number=!text%%b!
    if "!text%%b!"==" " (
        set nul=0
    ) ELSE (
        set /a binary1=%number% %% 2
        set /a number=%number% / 2
        set /a binary2=%number% %% 2
        set /a number=%number% / 2
        set /a binary3=%number% %% 2
        set /a number=%number% / 2
        set /a binary4=%number% %% 2
        set /a number=%number% / 2
        set /a binary5=%number% %% 2
        set /a number=%number% / 2
        set /a binary6=%number% %% 2
        set /a number=%number% / 2
        set /a binary7=%number% %% 2
        set /a number=%number% / 2
        set /a binary8=%number% %% 2
        set /a number=%number% / 2
        set outBin=%outBin% %binary8%%binary7%%binary6%%binary5%%binary4%%binary3%%binary2%%binary1%
    )
)
echo INPUT: !text!
echo ASCII: !ascii!
echo BINARY:!outBin!
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SomethingDark fixed your issue, but I had a bash at streamlining your code.

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%1"=="/?" (
    call :help
    exit /b
)


rem set Upper case ascii values
   for /L %%a in (65, 1, 90) do (
        cmd /c exit /b %%a
        set AsciiU.!=ExitCodeAscii!.=.%%a
    )

rem set Lower case ascii values
   for /L %%a in (97, 1, 122) do (
        cmd /c exit /b %%a
        set AsciiL.!=ExitCodeAscii!.=.%%a
    )
  rem set asciiU & pause
  rem set asciiL & pause

rem separate the input text from the switch, and remove any spaces
    set "text=%*"
    set "text=%text:/b =%"
    set "text=%text:/t =%"
    set "input=%text%"
    set "text=%text: =%"

if "%1"=="/b" (
    call :convBinary
    pause
    exit /b
)
if "%1"=="/t" (
    call :convText
    pause
    exit /b
)
echo [CONV] That command is not recognized.
exit /b

:help
echo Converts text or binary, or binary to text.
echo.
echo    Stynax: CONV [conversion] {options} [text]
echo.
echo    /b     Converts given text to binary.
echo    /t     Converts given binary to text.
echo.
exit /b

:convBinary
set "ResultAscii="
for /L %%a in (0, 1, 100) do (
   if "!text:~%%a,1!"=="" goto :set
   for /f "tokens=2,4 delims=." %%c in ('set ascii') do (
     if "!text:~%%a,1!"=="%%c" set ResultAscii=!ResultAscii! %%d
   )
)
:set
set "ResultBin="
for %%a in (!ResultAscii!) do (
   set number=%%a
        set /a binary1=number %% 2, number=number / 2
        set /a binary2=number %% 2, number=number / 2
        set /a binary3=number %% 2, number=number / 2
        set /a binary4=number %% 2, number=number / 2
        set /a binary5=number %% 2, number=number / 2
        set /a binary6=number %% 2, number=number / 2
        set /a binary7=number %% 2, number=number / 2
        set /a binary8=number %% 2, number=number / 2
        set ResultBin=!ResultBin! !binary8!!binary7!!binary6!!binary5!!binary4!!binary3!!binary2!!binary1!
)

echo INPUT: !input!
echo ASCII: !ResultAscii:~1!
echo BINARY:!ResultBin:~1!
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you Foxidrive, you really helped simplify the code and solved the problem. By the way, I am quite new to using variable expansion and delayed expansion so I had no clue what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

You're still inside a `for` loop when you create the `%number%`, `%outBin%`, and `%binary1-8%` variables for the first time, which means that they aren't defined during the initial variable expansion. Replace them with their delayed expansion versions.

```
    set /a binary1=!number!%%2
    set /a number=!number!/2
    set /a binary2=!number!%%2
    set /a number=!number!/2
    set /a binary3=!number!%%2
    set /a number=!number!/2
    set /a binary4=!number!%%2
    set /a number=!number!/2
    set /a binary5=!number!%%2
    set /a number=!number!/2
    set /a binary6=!number!%%2
    set /a number=!number!/2
    set /a binary7=!number!%%2
    set /a number=!number!/2
    set /a binary8=!number!%%2
    set /a number=!number!/2
    set outBin=!outBin! !binary8!!binary7!!binary6!!binary5!!binary4!!binary3!!binary2!!binary1!
```

Comment: Thank you SomethingDark for identifying the problem and providing an explanation.